# How can i get manufacturer image in manucarturer page in opencart2.0.2.0?

Tags: image, syntax-error, opencart2.x

I am using opencart version 2.0.2.0 and now i am trying to get image or image url in manufacturer page.

I have added the code in `catalog/controller/product/manufacturer.php`

```
$manufacturer_image = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturer($manufacturer_id);

        if($manufacturer_image){
            $this->data['manufacturers_img'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($manufacturer_image['image'], 120, 120);
        }else{
            $this->data['manufacturers_img'] = false;
        }
```

and call it in `catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/manufacturer_list.tpl`

```
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer['href']; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></a>
      <?php echo ($manufacturers_img) ? '<img src="'.$manufacturers_img.'" alt="'.$manufacturers.'" />' : $manufacturers ;?><br />
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

But it's getting error in my `/index.php?route=product/manufacturer` page

> Notice: Undefined variable: manufacturers_img in
>   /data1/opencart-2.0.2.0/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/manufacturer_list.tpl
>   on line 32Array

Comment: seems like you are confused with the, manufacturer list page and detail page,

Comment: I am not confused at all, i want to display image in manufacturer list page, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets be clear `ControllerProductManufacturer`  `index()` shows list and `info()` shows detail of the mfg,

```
//catalog/controller/product/manufacturer.php:46
```

Replace

```
$data['categories'][$key]['manufacturer'][] = array(
```

with

```
$manufacturer_image = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturer($result['manufacturer_id']);

if($manufacturer_image){
 $mfg_img = $this->model_tool_image->resize($manufacturer_image['image'], 120, 120);
}else{
 $mfg_img = false;
}

$data['categories'][$key]['manufacturer'][] = array(
'image'=>$mfg_img,
```

And in `catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/manufacturer_list.tpl:30`
inside loop

```
<?php if($manufacturer['image']):?>
  <img src="<?php echo $manufacturer['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $manufacturer['name'];?>">
<?php endif;?>
```